# Meteor: Can I check if a plain js object pass a MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I would need to filter a plain JS object using a MongoDB request (Meteor server side) this ideally without inserting it into a DB, is this possible ?

Something like `Mongo.match(myPlainObject, {"fieldName":"valueExpected"});`

Comment: Are you just checking fields by name or do you need mongo operators like `$gt`?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I would need mongo operations. For fields filtering it's trivial.

Comment: Some packages such as `aldeed:simple-schema` greatly increase the capacities of `check`s. Have you considered using one?

Comment: @Kyll even underscorejs is helping alot, here I am not looking for an alternative, the point is being to use the same mongodb query description on the client and on the server. Again, perhaps the answer is simply *no*

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do this within Mongo? You can test JSON objects using the built-in [Check](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check) functionality in Meteor. A big advantage is that this test can be made available on both client and server, which you often want to do for efficiency/security.

You can use Check for date ranges or anything else as well. Whatever is not covered by the predefined matches, can be done like this:

```
NonEmptyString = Match.Where(function (x) {
  check(x, String);
  return x.length > 0;
});
check(arg, NonEmptyString);
```

You could write any date related matches you need. (Keeping in mind that you can also make sure it is in fact a Date by stating:

```
check(arg,Date);
```

Comment: "Check" is not enough for ensuring a date range or more complex operations, perhaps there is just no way to do so without adding the object to a db aside.

Comment: (Moved my reply into my original answer.)

Comment: Simply put, I can't think of things you could express in a Mongo query, but not in `check` & `Match`, since `Match.Where` allows for **any** Javascript to be used.

Comment: By the way, if you use the [Collection Hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks) package, you can even prevent unmatched JSON objects from being inserted in a very easy way...